# Run a Flask web app in a virtual private server without showing the code

Tags: python, flask

I'm developing a web application with flask for an acquaintance of mine, who will then host the website on a VPS. Since I don't want to give my source code as well, but only the service, is there a way to run it on the VPS without making the source code visible?

Comment: If it is a flask app, then the python code will not be visible. If by source code you mean HTML/CSS/Javascript, then no - there is no way. If you don't want your javascript stolen then your best bet is to obfuscate it. There are a ton of different obfuscation tools for javascript, just google "js obfuscator."